# how to enable mobile zoom function in kinetic js

Tags: iphone, html, zooming, kineticjs, pan

I am creating a website with **kinetic js + html5** canvas, it display nicely in web but i having problem when the site display in mobile, May i know is there any way to **"unlock**" the mobile pan and zoom function in kinetic js ?

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a KineticJS plugin to make it easy to make pannable and pinchable Layer. Feel free to check/use it: [PinchLayer plugin](https://github.com/eduplus/pinchlayer)

Answer (score 0):

What you could look for are JavaScript 'gesture' libraries like jGestures which support gestures which would be the pan and zoom functions.

You can also write a function of your own which records touch positions and analyze that to check if it's a 'swipe' and then that could mean pan or zoom.

Otherwise you need to build a button or something which will allow panning or zooming when you touch or drag it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the property `listening` to `false` when you create your stage.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'my_container',
    listening: false
});
```